# How to generate UserID as created with new user registration?

Tags: asp.net, auto-generate, userid

I have a normal database and not using any membership provider and I would like to auto-generate a new user ID which is created in database with a new user registration.

As seen below this is what I need.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is a GUID (in .net) or uniqueidentifier (in SQL).

If you are using Microsoft SQL Server you can execute the following T-SQL:

```
DECLARE @ID uniqueidentifier;
SET @ID = NEWID();
```

...and then execute your INSERT statement.

If you prefer to generate the ID in VB.NET you can use the following code:

```
Dim id as Guid = Guid.NewGuid()
```

Comment: Instead of New Guid() use Guid.NewGuid().  New Guid() returns a newly instantiated object whose value is Guid.Empty.  Guid.NewGuid() returns one whose value is actually initialized to something useful.

Comment: @pseudocoder-Sorry for the late reply-First thanks for your answer which makes very easy to create but there is a slight modification with that as it creates only an empty guid with all 0's to modify that I have modified it to  Dim id As Guid = Guid.NewGuid() then worked perfectly.

Comment: @ChrisLively Thank you, updated.  Obviously you can tell which method I usually use :)